# Qt QGroupBox добавить QRadioButton

Tags: qt

```
QGroupBox *m_packSelectGroupBox = new QGroupBox("Тип пакета", this);
```

Как в эту "коробку" добавить QRadioButton. Пробовал вот так:

```
QRadioButton *m_packEthernetRadioButton = new QRadioButton("Ethernet", this);
m_packSelectGroupBox->children().append(m_packEthernetRadioButton);
```

Метод append требует константную ссылку:

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h:507: candidate: void QList::append(const T&) [with T = QObject*]
 Q_OUTOFLINE_TEMPLATE void QList::append(const T &t)
                           ^
```

Честно пытался передавать разыменованный указатель на константу:

```
const QRadioButton *m_packEthernetRadioButton = new QRadioButton("Ethernet", this);
m_packSelectGroupBox->children().append(*m_packEthernetRadioButton);
```

Ругается вот так:

`.../startscreen.cxx:12: error: no matching function for call to 'QList::append(const QRadioButton&) const'
     m_packSelectGroupBox->children().append(*m_packEthernetRadioButton);
                                                                             ^`
Если все таки у мемя замылился мозг и ошибка тупая, то поменять текст этой радио кнопки можно только const_cast'ом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B **QGroupBox** следует добавить нужный выравниватель (наследника от **QLayout**), а уж в него добавлять остальные виджеты стандартным образом.

Comment: Да, это должно было быть очевидно изначально. Ибо куда добавлять! Спасибо!